# Convert CR line break using SplFileObject

Tags: php, line-breaks

I write a class than extend SplFileObject to open a CSV and having a associative array. It's works but not if the the csv file use CR line break.

I know you can convert string line break like that:

```
$string = str_replace($this::CRLF, $string::LF, $file);
$string = str_replace($this::CR, $string::LF, $file);
```

But I was wondering how I can convert the line break in my constructor.

How I create my file:

```
$file = new CSVFile(__DIR__ . '/../../Resources/data/myfile.csv');
```

Class CSVFile.php

```
use \SplFileObject;

class CSVFile extends SplFileObject
{
    private $keys;    

    public function __construct($file)
    {
        parent::__construct($file);
        $this->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        parent::rewind();
        $this->keys = parent::current();
        parent::next();
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return array_combine($this->keys, parent::current());
    }

    public function getKeys()
    {
        return $this->keys;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite sure what you want to do, but have you tried this?  `ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',true);`

Comment: I'm importing CSV file with a class extending SplFileObject... Your idea is good I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing this (expect there is some support from php which I dont know about) is reading the file, replacing the line breaks, writing to a temporary file and then open the temp file.

Comment: That can work with small files. You can just a string variable without the need to write it. But I want to keep the advantage to read line by line in case of very big file...

Comment: @gagarine I can't see the problem? Why not reading a line writing it to the temp file then reading the temp file line by line and parse it ?! You could even write a CSV parser yourself ... its pretty much readline(), explode()

Comment: that's the point, I can't read line by line because line break are not detected :).